# Finding the General Solution to a Homogeneous Linear Differential Equation (of second order) with repeated roots. [Proof]

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation of the form $\ddot{y}+A\dot{y}+By=0$, where $A$ and $B$ are constants. Suppose, $A^2=4B$, implying that the characteristic equation of this ODE has repeated roots. In that case if $r_1$ is the repeated root, the general solution of the ODE is $y=c_1e^{r_1x}+c_2xe^{r_1x}$. Now I am aware of two methods through which one may explain why $c_2xe^{r_1x}$ is also a solution. First, is the reduction of order and the second is through Abel's theorem. But recently, I've come across another reasoning, which appears to be different and incomprehensible to me.

The relevant part is shown below:

Equation (22): $L y=D^n y+a_1D^{n-1} y+....+a_{n-1}D^1 y+a_ny=0$

Equation (23): $L e^{rx}=(r^n+a_1r^{n-1}+....+a_{n-1}r+a_n)e^{rx}$

Equation (24): $r^n+a_1r^{n-1}+....+a_{n-1}r+a_n=0$

[image]

I don't understand, why must the partial derivative with respect to $r$ be equal to zero.

Comment: I'm a little confused on notation: is $L$ an operator and does $D^n$ represent the $n$-th derivative?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

From the equation
$$ Le^{rx}=(r-r_1)^2(r-r_3)\cdots(r-r_n)e^{rx} $$
If we take the partial derivative with respect to $r$, then we obtain a sum of products of monomials (and one exponential term), each of which contain $r-r_1$ as a factor.  That is,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial r}Le^{rx}&= 2(r-r_1)(r-r_3)\cdots(r-r_n)e^{rx} \\
&\qquad+(r-r_1)^2(r-r_4)\cdots(r-r_n)e^{rx} \\
&\qquad+\cdots \\
&\qquad+(r-r_1)^2(r-r_3)\cdots(r-r_n)re^{rx}
\end{align*}
(and, of course, since $L$ is linear and we have sufficiently smooth functions, we have $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}L=L\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$).
Now evaluate this expression at $r=r_1$ to obtain $0$.